# How to theme Logintoboggan Access Denied Login Page

Tags: theming, authentication-authorization

I am looking to override Logintoboggan's default access denied login page. I can't seem to find what I name the template file and what the defaults are that are required. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming Drupal 7, if you are trying to override LT's `toboggan/denied` page, eg, what overall structure you see when you land on `www.example.com/toboggan/denied`, you could copy your theme's `page.tpl.php` to `page--toboggan--denied.tpl.php` and modify whatever you wanted in there. (If Drupal 6, the new name would be `page-toboggan-denied.tpl.php`.)

If you are instead (or also) trying to override the output of LT's theme function that produces the `You are not authorized to access this page` message on that page, you could create a function in your theme's `template.php` file:

```
function YOUR_THEME_lt_access_denied($variables) {
  return t("Whoa, Dude!  You aren't allowed in here!");
}
```

that would override LT's `theme_lt_access_denied()` function, which is just a quick:

```
function theme_lt_access_denied($variables) {
  return t('You are not authorized to access this page.');
}
```

Or, you could instead create a template file called `lt-access-denied.tpl.php` in your theme that would accomplish the same thing with some potentially more fanciness:

```
<?php 
  // contents of lt-access-denied.tpl.php
?>
<div class="tsk-tsk">
  Whoa, Dude!  You aren't allowed in here!
</div>
```

In any case, if you are trying to override any of the other theme functions in LT, or any other module for that matter, you would first look in the module and search for the [hook_theme()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7) to see what's available, and in LT, that would be the `logintoboggan_theme()` function found in the `logintoboggan.module` file.  Another great resource is [Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions](https://drupal.org/node/1089656) which details the template names and variants used in Drupal core modules.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function in your theme's `template.php` file.  This function below is the theme hook you're looking for... (from looking at the logintoboggan module ver. 7.x-1.3)

```
/**
 * Theme the Access Denied message.
 */
function theme_lt_access_denied($variables) {
  return t('You are not authorized to access this page.');
}
```

That means, in your custom theme you can make your own theme function. Like this:

```
/**
 * Theme the Access Denied message.
 */
function CUSTOMTHEMENAME_lt_access_denied($variables) {
  return 'WHATEVER HTML/TEXT YOU WANT';
}
```

You can even make a preprocess function that can add to the `$variables` element in the function above like so:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_hook.
 */
function CUSTOMTHEMENAME_preprocess_lt_access_denied(&$variables) {
  $variables['MYNEWVAR'] = 'NEWVAR';
}
```

Then you can pull `$variables['MYNEWVAR']` out of the `$variables` var in the `CUSTOMTHEMENAME_lt_access_denied` function and somehow use it, like this...

```
/**
 * Theme the Access Denied message.
 */
function CUSTOMTHEMENAME_lt_access_denied($variables) {
  return $variables['MYNEWVAR']; // which would be 'NEWVAR';
}
```

Comment: FYI: `theme_module_whatever()` functions can be overridden by a `module-whatever.tpl.php` template in your theme as well.